# ¿Como usar ciclo for en bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ciclos

Tengo un pequeño script de bash que no funciona de la manera que quiero

Aquí esta el código

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "Escriba la cantidad de letras"
read x
for i in $x;do
echo "Letra $i"
read y
echo $y
done
#export Mensaje
#./recibir.sh
```

Imagen del error logico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que debería de hacerme una repetición del echo el numero de veces que ingrese en el echo superior, pero solo me lo hace una vez y no comprendo muy bien la logica del for en bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El `for` de bash itera sobre un **conjunto de valores**; es similar al `for ... in` o al `foreach` de otros lenguajes.

Se ve mejor con un ejemplo:

```
for idx in *.sh;
 do echo $in;
done;
```

1. Bash crea una sequencia que contiene todos los archivos que coinciden con el patron.

   [ archivo1.sh archivo2.sh archivo3.sh ]
2. `for` itera sobre los elementos de la sequencia generada.

idx = archivo1.sh -> ...

idx = archivo2.sh -> ...

Para `for` numéricos, deberías hacer

```
for i in $(seq 1 $END)
```

Comment: Buena respuesta. Pequeño comentario: `seq 1 $END` y `seq $END` son equivalentes, pues por defecto `seq` empieza por 1.

Answer (score 2):

Para complementar la respuesta de @Trauma.

"for" hace un poco más que iterar sobre un conjunto de valores, o mejor dicho, ese conjunto de valores se genera para después iterar sobre él, también que opera bajo premisas, tal como se haría en c y lo hace de varias maneras:

1. `for name in < secuencia separada por espacios >;do lista de comandos;done`
2. `for ((expr1;expr2;expr3));do lista de comandos;done`

Esto se puede consultar en `man 1 bash`.

Menciono esto porque después de in, en el ejemplo 1, el bucle for trabaja sobre expansiones, es decir:

```
for archivo in carpeta/*
do
    echo $archivo
done
#es equivalente a
for archivo in "$(ls carpeta)"
do
    echo $archivo
done
```

Son equivalentes pero trabajan con diferentes tipos de expansiones, el primero fue sobre pathname expansion y el segundo fue sobre command substitution, pero también se puede hacer sobre brace expansion, es decir:

```
for i in {1..4}
do
  echo $i
done
1
2
3
4
```

O un ejemplo un poco más complejo en el cual puedes combinarlas:

```
for archivo in ca1/sc{2,3}/*foo
do
    echo $archivo
done
```

Te imprimirá todos los archivos que terminen con foo y que estén dentro de las carpetas sc2 y sc3 que a la vez están dentro de la carpeta ca1.

Lo de las expansiones también puedes verlo en `man bash`, en la sección de EXPANSIONS. Es importante notar que el orden en que se expanden las cadenas tiene un orden de prioridad.

Digo esto de las expansiones debido a que considero que es necesario aclararlo puesto que hay cuestiones como estas:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057870/bash-script-for-i-in-x-y/1059139#1059139

En el segundo ejemplo que @Allex puso, puedes ver que también se puede iterar sobre la expansion de brace expansion sobre un array.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, bienvenido a [es.so]

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que deseas es hacer un **for tipico** de 0 a x donde x es leido de una variable y representa el limite de repeticiones puedes utilizar el for con sintaxis muy similar a lenguaje C.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Ingrese el número de repeticiones para el ciclo for: "
read r
echo "Iniciando el for: "
for((i=0; i<r; i++)); do
        echo $i;
done
```

Por otra parte bash soporta el foreach en la misma estructura for, el foreach es muy utíl para leer arrays te dejo un ejemplo practico:

```
#!/bin/bash
r=("one two" "two" "3" "5")
for row in "${r[@]}"; do
        echo $row
done
```

**"${r[@]}"**

- Hace referencia al array $r
- Si la posicion es $r[**@**] "@" entonces haces referencia a todos los elementos del array es decir ("one two" "two" "3" "5"), posiciones(0, 1, 2, 3)=@
- Al estar entre comillas "${r[@]}" cada elemento resultante sera una sola cadena esto evitara que "one two" se interprenten como dos cadenas diferentes.
- Finalmente el for una vez ordenados los datos resultantes itera los elementos del arreglo y los imprime.