# Auditoría de accesos a mySQL usando scripts en bash para CentOS

Tags: mysql, bash, script, centos

Estoy intentando hacer un script escrito en bash para auditar los accesos a mySQL en la distribucion CentOS.
Mi experiencia en scripts es bastante limitada, pero dado que activando la variable "general_logs", puedes ver en un fichero de texto fuera de la aplicación de mySQL todas las actividades realizadas en mySQL, incluida los accesos permitidos y denegados, que es lo que estoy buscando.
Y eso he intentado, usando `grep`, la fecha y buscando `connect` debería poder ver la línea donde se supone que están.
Edit: un poco de google me ha revelado el secreto: encadenar `greps` con tuberias, ahora el problemas es conseguir que el script coja variables y las use para buscar la fecha deseada, que me da errores de sintaxis (que por supuesto no se identificar.
Adjunto pantallazos:
[image: ERROR!]
Mi trabajo actual
[image: trabajo actual]
Agradeceré cualquier consejo para hacer si quiera que funcione un poco.
Gracias!
PD: mantengo editado mi trabajo actual!

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar algo como :

`grep "$ano-$mes-$dia" /var/lib/mysql/localhost.log | grep "Connect"`

o si en la linea que buscas, aparece primero la fecha y luego Connect puede hacerse así

`grep "$ano-$mes-$dia.*Connect" /var/lib/mysql/localhost.log`

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias inconsistencias en tu código, por ejemplo, ¿Cómo sabe bash qué son las variables ano, mes y día?, es decir, dentro de ese script no tienen ningún valor porque no se lo haz asignado, entonces `mes=$mes` asigna a la variable "mes" el valor que tiene la variable "mes" pero como mes no tiene valor alguno, entonces le asigna una cadena vacía.

Así que supongo que quieres hacer algo con los parámetros y para eso utiliza las variables "$1", "$2", "$3", etc para atrapar los parámetros del programa. Es decir, si ejecutas un programa así:

```
$ ./programa param1 hola param3
```

Entonces, dentro del código, `$1` es "param1", `$2` es "hola" y `$3` es "param3". Ahí es donde puedes meter lo de ano, dia y mes.

Pero la clave del problema de tu código es debido a que `for` opera bajo una lista de items o bajo una expresión aritmética. Puedes ver más información oficial [aquí](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs) o puedes ver una pregunta con temática relacionada [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33046/como-usar-ciclo-for-en-bash-script/183933#183933).

Entonces en tu `for`, al sustituir la variable "ano" por su contenido, que es una cadena vacía, espera algo de la forma `for variable in [ lista ]`, sólo reconoce o nada o el token `in`, y como le estás pasando `$mes`, te responde "Hey, yo no espero $mes". Ahora, aún no te ha dado el error pero, en el caso del `grep`, lo que grep utiliza es un patrón y un archivo o un flujo. Es decir, tu toda tu pipe `grep patron | grep patron archivo` se va a quedar atorado en el primer `grep` puesto que está esperando un archivo o un flujo por el stdin. Por lo que necesitarías algo como lo mencionado por @gustavovelascoh

```
grep "$ano-$mes-$dia.*Connect" /var/lib/mysql/localhost.log
```

Lo cuál le pasa a `grep`como primer parámetro un patrón a buscar y como segundo parámetro el archivo dónde buscar el patrón. Eso lo puedes consultar en `man grep`.

O dicho de otra manera, además de que el comando `for` lo utilizaste mal, no es necesario para lo que quieres hacer.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 3 ]
then
    echo "El numero de parametros bla bla"
    exit #Aqui se sale del programa.
fi

ano="$1"
mes="$2"
dia="$3"

grep "$ano-$mes-$dia" /var/lib/mysql/localhost.log | grep "Connect"
```

Lo que hace al final es buscar el patrón determinado por la cadena "$ano-$mes-$dia" (sustituyendo sus valores) en el archivo `/var/lib/mysql/localhost.log` y ese resultado de los que coincidan se filtra buscando el patron "Connect".

En el primer `grep` busca un patrón en archivo, en el segundo `grep` sólo usa el patrón y en lo que busca ese patrón es en lo que le llega por el *stdin* dado a través del *pipe* (que es el resultado del primer `grep`).

Ahora sólo tendrías que cuidar que los parámetros no te lleguen vacíos.